# Which model to use to handle multiple levels(10-12) in many categorical independent variables and a continuous dependent variable?

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I have a continuous dependent variable.
5 categorical independent variable with 7-12 levels in each.
Converting into dummy variables and using regression doesn't sound good as there will be so many variables.
Which analytical methods can be used here ?

Comment: Is it a ' self study" question? If yes give some data and  indicate the objective.

Comment: You really need to give us more details! How many observations, for instance.  Or better: tell us about the applied problem, in the language of the application.  Then maybe ...

Comment: 9053166 2330 144 21 196063 196047 129639 10316 1817 2310 308 13 1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

Comment: this is just one observation. All predictors are categorical, Dependent variable is click probability.We have more than 1 million observations.

Comment: Unless there is some kind of structure in the categorical predictors (maybe they are ordinal, or there is some kind of random effects you can exploit) I am afraid it doesn't look like a soluble problem. You essentially have about $10^5 = 100000$ unique groups and one million observations, thus roughly, your MLE estimate is going to be the average value from 10 observations.

Answer (score 0):

ANOVA is recommended when you have a continuous dependent variable, and a categorical independent variable.

Logistic regression could be used if you convert the dependent variable into a categorical one.